# Finding the Unique Arrays in an List of Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of arrays, say

```
List = [A,B,C,D,E,...]
```

where each A,B,C etc. is an nxn array.

I wish to have the most efficient algorithm to find the unique nxn arrays in the list. That is, say if all entries of A and B are equal, then we discard one of them and generate the list

```
UniqueList = [A,C,D,E,...]
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal-reproducible example?

Comment: Depending on how the arrays are stored, you might just be able to do `UniqueList = list(set(List))`

Comment: @MustafaQuraish I am not sure if you can convert that list to a set.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a faster way, but I think this should be pretty fast (using the built-in unique function of numpy and choosing axis=0 to look for nxn unique arrays. More detail in the [numpy doc](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)):

```
[i for i in np.unique(np.array(List),axis=0)]
```

Example:

```
A = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
B = np.array([[1,1],[1,2]])
List = [A,B,A]

[array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1]]), 
 array([[1, 1],
        [1, 2]]), 
 array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1]])]
```

Output:

```
[array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1]]), 
 array([[1, 1],
        [1, 2]])]
```